# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.maps.MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-2

Here is my activity code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.id.map, container, false);
}
```

and this is my LogCat

```
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alltaskass/com.example.alltaskass.Map}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at com.example.alltaskass.Map.onCreate(Map.java:35)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
03-22 11:53:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  ... 11 more
```

I alredy visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440606/mapview-inside-fragment-specified-child-already-has-a-parent) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684330/issue-with-nosavestateframelayout) solution but still I am not able to solve my problem, Please give me some solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I can't understand your code:

1. You are first trying to get a `MapView`:

   ```
   mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
   ```
2. Then you are trying to get `SupportMapFragment`:

   ```
   GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
   ```

from the same UI element: `R.id.map`

While `MapView` is a Google Map `API V1` element and the `SupportMapFragment` is from `API V2`.

What are you using in the `R.layout.map` layout? show us it's code.

if you want to use API V2, here a blog post I wrote on how to integrate a map in your application:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: `While MapView is a Google Map API V1` wrong its part of `Google Map API V2`